# typo in packages/Net/SMTP.php

Tags: wordpress, smtp

I think there is a typo on line 692 of
wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/Net/SMTP.php

`mMethod` should be `method` in the last line below, yes?

```
if (is_array($callback)) {
            if (!is_object($callback[0]) || !is_string($callback[1]))
                return PEAR::raiseError('Bad mMethod callback array');
        }
```

Should I fork the `civicrm-packages` repository, make the change there and submit a pull request?

Or is CiviCRM getting this code from elsewhere, and it would be more useful to make the change in the original source repo?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you should fork the repo and create a pull request against the Master branch which i assume is the branch with the issue. Please see this documentation on contributing to CiviCRM https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Contributing+to+CiviCRM+using+GitHub